# How can you get @@IDENTITY or SCOPE_IDENTITY() to work in SQL Server Compact Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-ce

In my SQL Server Compact Edition database, this works:

```
INSERT INTO Clients (Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix, IsMale)
VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO Clients (Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix, IsMale)
VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

What's the dialectual hold-up here?  I am passing it all in as only one string/command to SQL Server CE from VB.Net, if that makes any difference.

Originally I tried doing this with SCOPE_IDENTITY() and would have strongly preferred that, but apparently that's not supported?  If there is a work-around to the SCOPE_IDENTITY() issue, I would prefer an answer involving that work-around; if not, then I'd be good with an answer involving @@IDENTITY.

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious.  Do all columns allow null and is a row inserted?

Comment: From a quick google search that also returned your cross-posted question (grr) it seems like compact edition does not allow batch queries, so you will have to SELECT @@IDENTITY in another query right after.  You might want to use a transaction so you don't get bad values in the event of lots of users hitting the database at the same time.

Comment: SQL Server Compact is not a multi-user database

Comment: cross-posted question?

Comment: @Blam As stated the insert statement works on its own.

Comment: Not my question.  The second insert doesn't work is not defined.  Does the second insert but not return an identity.  Or does the second not even insert.

Comment: Alright.  I didn't see that earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Er... you cant If you google either of these commands they give only full blown SQL as the supported versions.